# How to update ("check") a specific checkbox in jquery without nesting the find?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

Finding the element is one thing, updating a particularly indexed one is the question here.

Given basic HTML for a group of three checkboxes such as

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Test!!!!!
<input name='cars' type='checkbox' value="primary" checked/>
<input name='cars' type='checkbox' value="secondary"/>
<input name='cars' type='checkbox' value="tertiary"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I can use jquery to select all the checkboxes with

```
$("input").prop( "checked", true );
```

However, how can I target just one checkbox such as the middle one?

I tried

```
$("input")[1].prop( "checked", true );
```

But I get `prop is not a function`

and `$("input")[1].prop( "checked", true );` returns [] with no change.

It looks like I found one option which is a nested find, e.g.

```
$($("input")[1]).prop( "checked", true );
```

Is there a cleaner way than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`.eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) at this context,

```
$("input").eq(1).prop( "checked", true );
```

If you use bracket notation, then it will return the plain node object. And that doesn't have a function called `.prop()` in its prototype. So that wont work, will cause error.

And this nesting `$($("input")[1]).prop( "checked", true );`. It works because `$(nodeObject)` will be converted into a jquery object so over it you can access jquery functions like `prop()`.

Comment: Confirmed, this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nth-of-type` selector

```
$("input:nth-of-type(2)").prop( "checked", true );
```

Comment: Yes, this also worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just found that one option is using `.checked = false` against the first instance (`[1]`) of the `"input"` selector, i.e.

```
$("input")[1].checked = false;
```